# Can emails with firebaseapp.com domain be phishing emails?

Tags: firebase, security, phishing

I received 30+ emails in all languages (often eastern European) that always say the same thing :

"hello

We received a request to access project-0000000000 with this email address. If you want to sign in with your (your email) account, click this link:

Access to project-0000000000

If you didn't request this connection, ignore the email.

With respect,

project-0000000000 team"

I have received 30+ of these, without any prior action on my side. They generally have an URL "leading to the project". The URL seems based on firebase as well (xxxxxxx.page.link/?link=https://0000000000.firebase.com/...), but I wonder if it could be malicious, depending on what comes at the end of the URL, I guess.

If it's an attack, I guess the vector attack is the URL, because I cannot see any other option.

If it's not an attack, I wonder why on earth I receive all the emails, and what I can do about it.

The strangest thing, for me, is that I once received an email in Turkish thanking me for my contribution to one project. This email had no URL, so no obvious attack vector. I don't know if it was a case of social engineering, or if someone is impersonating my email address to use firebase.

Do someone know what could be going on ?

Comment: A now-deleted answer links to a news story with an explanation: https://threatpost.com/crooks-tap-google-firebase-in-fresh-phishing-tactic/155967/

Answer (score 1):

It's spam, I've been getting those emails on different languages lately. Do not click any links in them!